# systemd "Failed to set up mount namespacing" in Docker container

Tags: systemd, docker, openvpn, namespace

I recently updated a Docker that uses systemd internally from Debian stretch to Debian buster.
And since then it's not working.

So accoding to `systemctl status` it fails to setup the namespace:

```
Dec 10 14:22:11 f6f3e33e6bf2 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN tunnel for apu__ssl_vpn_config...
Dec 10 14:22:11 f6f3e33e6bf2 systemd[1736]: openvpn-client@apu__ssl_vpn_config.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: Permission denied
Dec 10 14:22:11 f6f3e33e6bf2 systemd[1736]: openvpn-client@apu__ssl_vpn_config.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/sbin/openvpn: Permission denied
Dec 10 14:22:11 f6f3e33e6bf2 systemd[1]: openvpn-client@apu__ssl_vpn_config.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Dec 10 14:22:11 f6f3e33e6bf2 systemd[1]: openvpn-client@apu__ssl_vpn_config.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 10 14:22:11 f6f3e33e6bf2 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN tunnel for apu__ssl_vpn_config.
```

Now I have had a similar issue with elasticsearch, which I fixed by adding a drop in unit config containing:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=false
NoNewPrivileges=yes
```

Though sadly that doesn't fix the issue this time.

I also found this exact issue occuring when using LXC (or LXD?), though I don't know how to fix this with docker.

Additionally I start the container like this:

```
docker run -dt \
    --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /tmp \
    --volume /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    --device=/dev/net/tun \
    --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
    --cap-add NET_ADMIN \
    <container>
```

Any pointers are much apprechiated.

Comment: *Permission denied* : Which user is running the service?

Comment: @Fiximan everything is root.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to run the container in priviledged mode like this:
(Also `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` was not necessary)

```bsh
docker run -dt \
    --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /tmp \
    --volume /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    --device=/dev/net/tun \
    --cap-add NET_ADMIN \
    --privileged \
    <container>
```